# Pandas groupby count one column against the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe with 11 million rows:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to count how many users tweeted the same number of tweets using the `'user_id'` column and the plot the histogram (y-axis: number of users, x-axis: number of tweets).

I tried this:

```
user_tweet_df.groupby('tweet_count').count()
```

This couldn't work. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide a typical out put you are expecting as a table and as a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if below will work for you. Use [pandas docs on visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) to customize your graph as needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[312,412,521,577,614,753,965,989],
                    'user_name':['Mary','Bob','Hans','Nicole','Chris','Matt','Carol','Khan'],
                    'tweet_count':[207,35,35,1,2,1,1,15]})
print(tabulate(tweets_df, headers='keys'), '\n')

grouped_df = tweets_df.groupby('tweet_count').count()[['user_id']]
print(tabulate(grouped_df, headers='keys'), '\n')

grouped_df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]